# Unable to run first WCF service

Tags: wcf, .net-4.0

This is my first WCF service and I am getting an error:

```
Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible. Make sure your service is running and exposing metadata.
```

Code:

```
 namespace WcfMathServiceLibrary
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IMath
    {
        [OperationContract]
        double Add(double i, double j);
        [OperationContract]
        double Sub(double i, double j);
        [OperationContract]
        Complex AddComplexNo(Complex i, Complex j);
        [OperationContract]
        Complex SubComplexNo(Complex i, Complex j);
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Complex
    {
        private int _real;
        private int _imaginary;

        [DataMember]
        public int real { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public int imaginary { get; set; }

    }




 namespace WcfMathServiceLibrary
{
    public class MathService : IMath
    {
        public double Add(double i, double j)
        {
            return (i + j);
        }

        public double Sub(double i, double j)
        {
            return (i - j);
        }

        public Complex AddComplexNo(Complex i, Complex j)
        {
            Complex result = new Complex();
            result.real = i.real + j.real;
            result.imaginary = i.imaginary + j.imaginary;
            return result;
        }

        public Complex SubComplexNo(Complex i, Complex j)
        {
            Complex result = new Complex();
            result.real = i.real - j.real;
            result.imaginary = i.imaginary - j.imaginary;
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Web.Config

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfMathServiceLibrary.MathService">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/WcfMathServiceLibrary/MathService/"/>
          </baseAddresses> 
        </host>
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WcfMathServiceLibrary.MathService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>

        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" >
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

I am not sure what is the issue. Could you please guide me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your contract may need to point to the interface and not the concrete implementation

```
<endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WcfMathServiceLibrary.IMath">
```

Comment: I didn't get you. Do I need to put anything in the address?

Comment: No just change the contract to point to the interface IMath and not MathService